# Symfony Form customize array for entity type

Tags: arrays, forms, symfony

In my Symfony2.6.6 project I have a `category` entity. I don't know how to say that properly but use the doctrine tree extension to create a tree with the `category` entity like:

- Category 1

  - Child Category 1
  - Child Category 2
- Category 2

  - Child Category 3
    ...

Now when creating the form type for creating a new Category I want to customize the array of the `parent` field.

The code I use

```
$builder->add('parent', 'entity', array('class' => 'AcmeBlogBundle:Category', 'property' => 'title'));
```

generates just an array with all the title as expected. But I want the array values to append a '-' for every level of the tree. Category 1 for example would be '- Category 1' and Child Category 1 would be '-- Child Category 1'. How can I do that?

Sorry if this has been asked before, I don't know how to search for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's say you have property **getLevel()** which would return your current item's level. Then in your Category entity file, create a simple method, for example **getIndentedTitle** thar would return your pre-defined category based on its level.

```
public function getIndentedTitle() {
    return sprintf(
        '%s %s',
         str_repeat('-', $this->getLevel()),
         $this->getTitle()
    );
}
```

The following code will add as many "-" symbols as your current category level and will append its title next to it.

Then in your form builder, you have to specify to use that method:

```
$builder->add('parent', 'entity', array('class' => 'AcmeBlogBundle:Category', 'property' => 'indentedTitle'));
```

More info on [str_repeat.](http://php.net/str_repeat)

Hope you got the idea.